# TRY doesn't CATCH error in BULK INSERT

Tags: t-sql, error-handling, try-catch, bulkinsert

Why in the following code TRY didn't catch the error and how can I catch this error?

```
BEGIN TRY
  BULK INSERT [dbo].[tblABC]
  FROM 'C:\temp.txt'
  WITH (DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',FIELDTERMINATOR = ';',ROWTERMINATOR = '\n')
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
  select error_message()
END CATCH
```

I just get this:

```
Msg 4860, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\temp.txt" does not exist.
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Capture BULK INSERT error 4863](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356310/sql-capture-bulk-insert-error-4863)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is one option that helps to catch this error:

```
BEGIN TRY
 DECLARE @cmd varchar(1000)
 SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[tblABC] 
  FROM ''C:\temp.txt'' 
  WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''widechar'',FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
 EXECUTE (@cmd)
END TRY

BEGIN CATCH
 select error_message()
END CATCH
```

After this I got the following error in CATCH:

```
Cannot bulk load. The file "C:\temp.txt" does not exist.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, this just made my life so much easier as I'm doing exactly this - using the Bulk Import to update data and tables and need to have errors let me know there is an issue with the import files.

Comment: That didn't worked for me :´>(

Answer (score 1):

You should add *MAXERRORS* parameter as zero, the default value is 10:

```
SET @cmd = 'BULK INSERT [dbo].[tblABC] 
  FROM ''C:\temp.txt'' 
WITH (MAXERRORS = 0, DATAFILETYPE = ''widechar'',FIELDTERMINATOR = '';'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'')'
```