# Bulk load data conversion error not captured with in try-catch block of a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, try-catch

I am facing an issue with bulk insert from a CSV to MSSQL table.  With try, catch block I cannot see any errors but when I execute without try catch block,  it gives following 3 errors.

> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bulk load data conversion error
>   (type mismatch or invalid character for the specified codepage) for
>   row 2, column 10 (InActiveDate).
>
> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an
>   error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>
> Msg
>   7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB
>   provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

when I set`MAXERRORS = 0`, with in `try catch block`,  it catches only the last error which is

> Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
>   Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

I created a procedure to catch errors and insert into a log table.  Is there any way to capture all 3 errors or the 1st error (which is more sensible to a developer) ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spr_BulkInsert] @FileToProcess varchar(200)
AS
        BEGIN TRY
        SELECT * INTO #Bulktest FROM test WHERE testID = 0;
        EXEC('BULK INSERT #Bulktest FROM '''+@FileToProcess+'''WITH (MAXERRORS = 0,FIELDTERMINATOR= ''|'',ROWTERMINATOR = ''\n'',FIRSTROW=2);')
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
           DECLARE @Message nvarchar(4000),@Severity int,@Number int;
           SELECT @Severity = ERROR_SEVERITY(),@Message = CONVERT(nvarchar(10),ERROR_NUMBER())+ N': '+ ERROR_MESSAGE();
           RAISERROR (@Message,@Severity, 1);
        END CATCH 
    END
    Calling procedure is 
        BEGIN TRY
        EXEC [dbo].[spr_BulkInsert] @FileToProcess = @FileName
        END TRY
        BEGIN CATCH
        EXEC [dbo].[spr_ErrorHandling] 
        END CATCH

    Thanks
```

Comment: Can you provide your code?

Comment: @scsimon, I am afraid to share the code due to sensitive data in database.  The prototype is

Comment: Hard to tell without your procedure. But this is a nifty article about the try catch blocks. Also, why not just work through your errors one at a time until you debug it?  http://sqlblog.com/blogs/alexander_kuznetsov/archive/2009/05/13/your-try-block-may-fail-and-your-catch-block-may-be-bypassed.aspx

Comment: HAHA, it happened again unfortunately. Just add it to your original post

Comment: @scsimon I updated the post with the prototype of my code.  I dont know about the horrible indentation.  But I hope this might help you to help me

Answer (score 0):

This is a Bug..See the [connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/592960/bulk-insert-error-with-severity-level-16-were-not-caught-by-try-catch-blocks) for more details.

**Description of Bug..:**.

> I am trying to bulk inserting the data from a flat file to a database table for which the datatypes of a specific column are not matching.
>
> In the above case i am receiving the following error message without TRY / CATCH block:
>
> Msg 4864, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Bulk load data conversion error (type mismatch or invalid character for
>   the specified codepage) for row 2, column 15 (ColumnName).
>
> Msg 4863, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 
>   Bulk load data conversion error (truncation) for row 3, column 13
>   (ColumnName).

Inspite of the severity level being 16 i dont see the error being caught by TRY / CATCH construct.

See this [question and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20356310/sql-capture-bulk-insert-error-4863) for some workarounds

Comment: Yes, I posted a comment on the bug as well.  But the bug was closed without any fix! And the workaround I see is to set MAXERRORS, which is why I tried setting MAXERRORS 0, in which case the catch block captures the last error(3rd one).  I am looking for an option to capture all 3 errors or the first error.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link to another post!